# ASP.NET Core - Unable to signIn with signInManager when app is published

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core application running locally where I can sign in without any problem. However, I am unable to sign in when I publish my app to my server. I get the following error: This page can’t be found. Could there be something I need to configure on my server to be able to login my application?

Here is the service I use to sign in:

```
public class IdentityAuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private UserManager<IdentityApplicationUser> userManager;
    private SignInManager<IdentityApplicationUser> signInManager;
    private RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;

    public IdentityAuthenticationService
    (
        UserManager<IdentityApplicationUser> userManager, 
        SignInManager<IdentityApplicationUser> signInManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager
    )
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.signInManager = signInManager;
        this.roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public async Task LoginAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        //This line is where the error comes from             
        var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, isPersistent: false, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (!result.Succeeded) {
            throw new InvalidLoginException();
        }
    }
    [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u published the project??
[Refer this link](https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1286/how-to-deploy-visual-studio-2013-web-application-project-to-discountasp_net-using-web-deploy-ftp.aspx)

And did u set a Start Default page? in webconfig?
something like this

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="120" name=".ASPXAUTH" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="default.aspx" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
</authentication>
```